# How to add additional property to a JSON string?

Tags: java, json, gson

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
Gson gson = new Gson()    
String s = gson.toJson(obj, type);
```

I want to add an additional property to above Json string s which does not exist in type. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use gson.toJsonTree(..) method to do the same, below is a working example for the same:-
1. Use the [toJsonTree(Object src)](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJsonTree-java.lang.Object-) method to get src object's equivalent representation as a tree of JsonElements.
2. Call the [getAsJsonObject()](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsJsonObject--) ON JsonElement retrieved in step 1 to get it as JsonObject.
3. Add property in [JsonObject](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) in step 2, using addProperty(..) method.

```
class Employee{

    public Employee(String name){
        this.name= name;
    }
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class GsonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Employee employee=new Employee("Amit");
        String s=gson.toJson(employee, Employee.class);
        System.out.println(s);
        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(employee);
        jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("dept", "IT");
        s=gson.toJson(jsonElement);
        System.out.println(s);
    }

/** Output
{"name":"Amit"}
{"name":"Amit","dept":"IT"}
*/
```

Your code change will be:-

```
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(obj);
jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty("new_property", "new_property_value");
s=gson.toJson(jsonElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use JsonParser and transform your jsonString to JsonElement and add your other properties. Hope it is useful. Sample code is below:

```
    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("name1");
    person.setSurname("surnma1");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(person, Person.class);

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(json);
    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("property1", "property1 value");

    // json2 is your new jsonString with additional property.
    String json2 = jsonObject.toString();
```